# Wordpress list child pages on child page using foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I'm using a foreach loop to list child pages on a parent page, which works great. However, the child pages don't list on a child page, which is what I'd like.

Here's what works for the parent page so far:

```
<?php

$nav = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);

$child_pages = get_posts($nav);

?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($child_pages as $child_page) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?=get_permalink($child_page->ID); ?>"><?=$child_page->post_title; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Ideally I'd like to keep using foreach rather than any other loop. I'm wondering if I need to add another loop inside my existing loop, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do here is to check if the current page is a child page using *wp_get_post_parent_id* - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_parent_id and then if the page is a child page - use the parent id, otherwise just use the post id. Something like this should work:

```
global $post;
if(wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID ))
{
    $nav = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_parent' => wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID )
    );
}
else{
    $nav = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
    );
}
$child_pages = get_posts($nav);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parent instead of post_parent

```
    <?php

    $nav = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'child_of' => $post->ID
    );

    $child_pages = get_posts($nav);

    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($child_pages as $child_page) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?=get_permalink($child_page->ID); ?>"><?=$child_page->post_title; ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

hope it helps

Comment: Hey - unfortunately that doesn't give me just the child pages of that parent. This gives me a list of all the pages. Thanks though.

Comment: i've changed the parent to child_of try that if it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
        <? foreach (get_posts(array('post_type' => 'page','orderby' => 'title','order' => 'ASC','post_parent' => $post->ID)) as $p) { ?>
            <?=$p->post_title; ?>
        <? } ?>
```